# Enabling RBAC on Existing AKS Clusters

Tags: azure, kubernetes

We are looking to enable RBAC on exisiting AKS clusters and need help with how we can proceed with this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If your talking about enabling Kubernetes RBAC (rather than integrating RBAC with AAD) then this cannot be enabled after a cluster is created, it must be done at creation. You will need to recreate the cluster.